# Timeout accessing Stack Overflow

Tags: support

I am suddenly unable to access Stack Overflow. The error says it's a code 522 at the host.  I have tried refreshing the page several times.

[image: timeout]

Comment: Same here.  Hopefully they are working on it.

Comment: 1 second after the linked question!

Comment: interesting, but meta work ok, and chats also work

Comment: Not exact literally) it's other branch (SO vs SF)

Comment: Code 522? IIRC, that's 'Coder needs assistance, shots fired'